# How to show tabs normally when 'set list'?

Tags: gvim, listchars

Sometime there is **0xa0** in my code, which causes compile error and hard to find out where it is because it's invisible.. I searched on google and found `set listchars=nbsp:.` can make the **0xa0** visible.

I want to enable `listchars` permanently, but it requires `set list`, which causes tabs are displayed as '^I'.

How can I enable `set list` and make tabs remain unchanged?

Comment: What is the value of listchars (`set listchars?`)? IIRC `'list'` wont display special characters for items not in listchars.

Comment: Only `set listchars=nbsp:.` and the tabs still displayed as '^I'.  I can confirm it is set correctly with command `set listchars`, it shows 'listchars=nbsp:.'

Comment: Ah; it may displaying the « control character » version (thats a `<C-i>` representation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Displaying `^I` for tab is the default Vi behavior. You could set the list character for tab to a spaces:

```
set listchars=nbsp:×,tab:\ \ ,trail:\ ,
set list
```

Note that I have added a definition for trailing spaces (to be displayed as spaces). Without it, the nbsp is not displayed.

**Alternative:** Use Syntax highlighting

Just add the following to your `vimrc`:

```
autocmd Syntax * syntax match NBSP "[\xa0]" containedin=ALL | highlight link NBSP Error
```

Comment: Same idea, same time!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes :-). Could you test in your environment, that the replacement char for `nbsp` is only displayed, when a replacement char for `trail` is defined?

Comment: given `set list listchars=nsbp:_` (not the exact char, but close enough), it is displayed. Setting trail seems to be optional for me.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I'm pretty sure it is a bug. Try it with `vim --clean`. I checked two versions on Linux (7.4 & 8.1.857) and Windows (8.1.x & cygwin 8.0.x).

Comment: Indeed... not sure whats causing me to not see it. Repro’d with `vim —clean` as you suggested

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Now to `set spell`.

Comment: It immediately appears! Regardless of trail or not. You should file a bug

Comment: Done. Bug  #3889

Answer (score 2):

One slightly hacky workaround that I’m not entirely satisfied with is to use the space character for listchars tab:

```
execute 'set listchars+=tab:  '
```

(Note that there are **2** spaces; the first character traditionally represents the start of a tab, and the second character is used for the "filler" space.)

I use myself a value more like

```
execute 'set listchars+=tab:» '
```

So that I can see where the tabs are.